# Procedures in Lisp

Tags: scheme, lisp, procedures

What would happen if I were to define the following procedure in Lisp:
**(define (p) (p))** 
What value would it return? I'm **not** new to programming but I'm reading this book that's kinda more in depth and uses Lisp for the examples and this one has got me confused.

Comment: The same as: "10 GOTO 10"

Comment: Is there any reason to suppose it's different from something like `int foo() { return foo(); }` in C or Java (tail-call optimization aside)?

Answer (score 6):

When executed, the procedure will create an infinite loop and it will never return a value. We're defining a recursive procedure called `p` whose body is a call to itself; because there is no base case, the procedure will never end. In a more familiar syntax (say, Python's) it's the same as this:

```
def p():
    return p()
```

Your procedure is being called in [tail position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), which Scheme can optimize to use a constant amount of space - whereas the Python interpreter can't do that optimization and will quickly crash due to a stack overflow.

Comment: Depending on the Lisp implementation (interpreter or high debug settings) there might be a stack overflow, too. Scheme requires TCO to be supported by an implementation, interpreter or compiler. Lisp does not.